# Excel Formula finding numbers in column?

Tags: excel

I have a column filled with numbers.  Some rows have more than one number and are separated by and underscore '_'.  I am trying to create a formula that will check to make sure all numbers in a range - say 1 through 300 are in the column.  But, everything I come up with is finding the number even if it is in another one.  For example, I am searching for 5 which I know is missing, but the row with 251 matches for the 5.

A sample section of the column:
20_21_22_23_30_130_131_185
20_21_22_23_157_185_233_234_245_246
24_40
24_40_41
24_40_343
28_76
28_254_255
30_44_130_131_226_342
30_76_145_193_224
30_130_131_185_226_245_246_317
31_32_33_35_36_43_44_45
31_32_33_35_36_126_127_128_130_131_187_226

I have a couple hundred rows and need to make sure I have all number listed.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your formula to instead of looking for number in string to look for "*number*" as this is your natural delimiter. or if you get your feed your numbers from any other particular column, let say from `B2` onwards, change it in formula to `"_" & B2 & "_"`

**EDIT**

as pointed out, this solution will miss the numbers if they are they appear first in the cell. two possibilities there, please bear in mind i am not sure on exact formula you use, and the volumne of cells you go through, one option is to feed in the column with preceding "_" and enter formula as array,  but this will somewhat slow down the calculation, another solution is to add a formula next to the original range which will be populate with a formula `="_"&B2`and populated down and do the search from this column instead

Comment: Closer - But, it still leaves out any numbers the appear first since there is no preceding underscore.

Comment: ah! i overlooked that, apologies, will update my answer

Comment: No problem!  It has me closer.  Doing something like =MATCH( "*_"&ROW(A2)&"_*",A:A, 0 ) now.

Comment: hmm, `MATCH` seems like a no go here: it only matches full string against cell or closest match if you sort the dataset and change last argument of the formula, you are better off with `FIND` or `SEARCH` as you are trying to find a string within a string.

Comment: You are correct.  I ended up pulling the column and dumping into WORD.  I replaced the '_' with a line break.  I copied the data back into spreadsheet.  Now, a simplified MATCH works and tells me what row the number appears on.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: i didn't see that one coming :)